# importing proto from different files

Tags: protocol-buffers

I maintain all my proto files in one folder. An overview:

```
protos
|
|__auth
|
|__some_other
```

Inside `auth` directory I have `auth_service.proto` `user.proto` etc.

But I am having issues with importing definitions form `user.proto`

In `auth_service.proto`:

```
syntax="proto3";

package auth;

import "auth/user.proto"; // Import "auth/user.proto" was not found or had errors.

message SomeMessage {
  User user = 1; // user is not defined
}
```

user.proto has the same package name:

```
syntax="proto3";

package auth;

message User{}
```

Protoc version: `libprotoc : 3.19.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be tricky.

One way to think about it is that you need to determine the root of the import path and then proto imports are relative to it.

Assuming `${PWD}` is the parent of `protos`.

Example #1:

If you use `${PWD}` as the `proto_path`:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--go_out=${PWD} \
  ${PWD}/protos/auth/auth_service.proto \
  ${PWD}/protos/auth/user.proto
```

Then the import should be `import "protos/auth/user.proto";`

Example #2:

If you use `protos` as the `proto_path`:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/protos \
--go_out=${PWD} \
  ${PWD}/protos/auth/auth_service.proto \
  ${PWD}/protos/auth/user.proto
```

Then the import should be `import "auth/user.proto";`.

> **NOTE** In all cases, the `proto` file references must be prefixed by (one of) a `proto_path`.

`settings.json`:

```
"protoc": {
    "path": "${workspaceRoot}/protoc-21.2-linux-x86_64/bin/protoc",
    "compile_on_save": true,
    "options": [
        "--proto_path=${workspaceRoot}/protoc-21.2-linux-x86_64/include",
        "--proto_path=${workspaceRoot}/protos",
        "--go_out=${workspaceRoot}"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The commands that you mentioned are for compiling protos right? When I am writing out the protos I get red underline in vscode pointing out errors(import error). given your answer is it safe to just ignore those?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I recreated your structure and opened using Visual Studio code - Insiders (`1.69.0-insider`) with `vscode-proto3`. I have a `protoc` section in settings. I can compile from within Visual Studio. I don't underline warnings (for some reason) but I do get warnings if I use the incorrect import (per above answer) or add a non-existent message.

Comment: can you put your protoc section that you mentioned here please? Might help me

Comment: Done [Adding padding to overcome minimum comment length]

Comment: Tried everything you suggested(using example 2). https://ibb.co/2dWtkrs Have a look at the vscode error

Comment: If you can run the equivalent `protoc` from the command-line, then the issue is with the extension or its configuration. I'm unable to repro your issue.